# Invalid read of size 8 - Stack ADT

Tags: c

In C code. This is my code (it's an exercise, I can do changes but i can't change the structures and test functions).

These are the stack node and stack structures:

```
/*structure of each node of the stack*/
struct stack_node_s {
    void *data; /*user provided data*/
    struct stack_node_s *next; /*pointer to the next node in the stack*/
};

/*defines the type of a stack node*/
typedef struct stack_node_s stack_node_t;

/*defines the structure of the stack*/
struct stack_s {
    stack_node_t *top; /*the top of the stack*/
    size_t size; /*size of the stack*/
};

/*defines the stack type*/
typedef struct stack_s* stack_t;
```

Stack operations functions:

```
stack_t stack_create()
{
  stack_t stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_s));
  if (stack == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to create a stack\n");
    abort();
  }

  stack->top = NULL;
  stack->size = 0;

  return stack;
}

void stack_destroy(stack_t stack, int destroy_data)
{
  if (stack != NULL) {
    stack_clear(stack, destroy_data);
    free(stack);
  }
}

void stack_push(stack_t stack, void *data)
{
  if (stack != NULL) {
    stack_node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(stack_node_t));

    if (node == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to create a stack node\n");
        abort();
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = node;
    stack->size += 1;
  }
}

void stack_pop(stack_t stack, int destroy_data)
{
  if (!stack_is_empty(stack)) {
    stack_node_t *node = stack->top;
    stack->top = stack->top->next;
    stack->size -= 1;

    if (destroy_data) {
        free(node->data);
    }

    free(node);
  }
}

void* stack_top(const stack_t stack)
{
  if (stack_is_empty(stack)) {
    return NULL;
  }

  return stack->top->data;
}

int stack_is_empty(const stack_t stack)
{
  if (stack->top == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

size_t stack_size(const stack_t stack)
{
  return stack->size;
}

void stack_clear(stack_t stack, int destroy_data)
{
  while (stack->top != NULL) {
    stack->size -= 1;
    stack_node_t *node = stack->top;
    stack->top = stack->top->next;

    if (destroy_data) {
        free(node->data);
    }
    free(node);
  }
}
```

Test function (edited):

```
void test_null()
{
  stack_t stack = NULL;
  assert( stack_size(stack) == 0 );
  assert( stack_is_empty(stack) ); //Here
  stack_push(stack, NULL);
  stack_clear(stack, 0);
  assert( stack_size(stack) == 0 );
  stack_destroy(stack, 0);
}
```

Compiles correctly but valgrind display this message:

```
Test case 'null'... ==4472== Invalid read of size 8
==4472==    at 0x10938F: stack_is_empty (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==    by 0x10948F: test_null (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==    by 0x1091D2: main (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4472== 
==4472== 
==4472== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4472==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==4472==    at 0x10938F: stack_is_empty (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==    by 0x10948F: test_null (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==    by 0x1091D2: main (in /home/francesco/Documents/stack/stack)
==4472==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4472==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4472==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4472==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4472==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

It seems the error is in stack_size function, but I haven't idea about it...
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

edit: I edited the code to show only the test function in which there's the problem. I added a control in stack_size function (if stack == NULL) and now it seems the problem is in stack_is_empty...

Comment: `stack_size` should simply have at the beginning `if (!stack) return 0;` Because it needs to handle the case that a `NULL` pointer is passed in - which is clearly what is being done in the `test_null` test case. Similarly NULL handling needs to be done in the other functions such as `stack_is_empty` (though that function should really just call `stack_size`).

Comment: Please try to minimize the test-cases to just preferably a single one that replicates the unwanted behavior. And then minimize that test-case even further until you don't get the error. Re-add the last bit (and reintroduce the error) and [edit] your question to show only that.

Comment: Code edited. Now there's only the test function in which there's the problem